# C++ Object or 2-dimensional Array as a Parameter?

Tags: c++, arrays

In a Tic Tac Toe game I creating for school I have five classes: Game (acts as a controller for the game), Player (base class), HumanPlayer and AIPlayer (both derived from Player), and Board.

Board contains a 2D array and some functions for displaying and working on the array. All three player classes have a function `makeAMove(Board &board)` which will choose a position on the board and place an X or an O.

As you can see `makeAMove` accepts a `Board` object as a parameter. Then the function will decide on a move and alter the Board object's board array. If I'm understanding correctly, the actual object being passed in will be altered and there will not be any need to return anything back.

Am I understanding this correctly? Would it be better to use the 2d array as the parameter instead?

Here is a condensed version of my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory> // auto_ptr

class Board
{
    public:
        Board()
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
            {
                for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
                    board[row][column] = ' ';
            }
        }

        void displayBoard()
        {
            std::cout << "\n-------------" << std::endl;

            for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
            {
                std::cout << "| " ;
                for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
                    std::cout << board[row][column] << " | ";
                std::cout << "\n-------------" << std::endl;
            }
        }

/*      My thought was to use getBoard to return the array rather than using the 
        object as a parameter       
        char getBoard()
        {
            return board[][3];
        }       
*/

    char getCell(int row, int column)
    {
        return board[row][column];
    }

    void setCell(int row, int column, char player)
    {
        board[row][column] = player;
    }

    private:
        char board[3][3];

};

class Player
{
    public:
        virtual void makeAMove(Board &board) = 0;   
};

class AIPlayer : public Player
{
    virtual void makeAMove(Board &board)
    {
        // do some work ont the board array
    }   
};

class HumanPlayer : public Player
{
    virtual void makeAMove(Board &board)
    {
        // do some work on the board array
    }
};

class Game 
{
    public: 
        Game(unsigned int players)
        {
            if (players == 1)
            {
                player1.reset (new HumanPlayer()); 
                player2.reset (new AIPlayer());
            }
            else 
            {
                player1.reset (new HumanPlayer());
                player2.reset (new HumanPlayer());
            }
        }

        void playGame()
        {
            player1->makeAMove(myBoard);
        }

    private:
        std::auto_ptr<Player> player1; // pointer to a Player object (C++11 has more secure unique_ptr)
        std::auto_ptr<Player> player2; // pointer to a Player object
        Board myBoard;
};

int main() 
{
    Game myGame(1);
    myGame.playGame();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes because you're passing the `Board` object by reference, any change to it in the function will alter the actual `Board` object. I think passing a `Board` object is a better idea, as it is better not to expose the actual implementation ( a 2D array in this case) of the game to the user. So passing as Board object gives more abstraction, which is good.

Answer (score 1):

`makeAMove` belongs in `board`. The player objects should decide what move to make, then call `board::makeAMove` to make the move. That way the player objects don't care what the internal representation of the board is.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the object by reference as you are instead of the array.  Any alterations made by the player on the board will persist.

`board` is a private member of `Board`.  It should only ever be returned by value and not by reference.  If you pass the 2d array to the player by Value any changes they make to the board will not persist.

Your `Player` classes will need to access `Board.setCell(int, int)`, in the `makeAMove(Board &board)` function and to do that they will need the board object.

However your `Players` classes will need to read the board. In order to make a move.  The `getCell(int,int)` function might be enough but it might also be tedious to nested loop through all of the cells.  A `getBoard` might be useful for a possible `decideMove` function.

Comment: Yes, you might be right. But I'm unsure how to return a 2d array in a getter.

Comment: You really shouldn't, unless the array was `std::vector<std::vector>` or `std::array<std::array>` from c++11.  Otherwise your players will not know the length of the arrays.  Maybe just have a `char[9]` instead of a 2D array?  Does it really need to be a 2D array?

Comment: No it doesn't. It just makes the user input easier. The user will first input a row and then a column. These numbers are then directly applied to the 2d array (after some validation). If I used a 1d array I would need to convert each row and column to a single index. Certainly not impossible, but I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: User inputs `row` `col`. Index is `(row*3 - 1) + (col -1)` or visa-versa depending on how you index the 1D array.  IMO that's much simpler than looping out 2D arrays.  And that line would go in `setCell`, if you use it

Comment: I'm not sure I see how that works. If the user enters row 1 and col 1, this translates to 2 + 0 = 2.

Comment: Okay if I use rows and col (0-2) then 3row + col = index.

Comment: Nope I'm wrong its `3*(row - 1) + (col - 1)`, If your args are not 0-offset.  Good lord was I wrong.